# How to add a spring application context to the java runtime to be used for integration tests within eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, junit

I am trying to add a test spring application context to the java runtime, so that my beans can be wired properly for my integration tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I solved it. I just had to add the folder containing my test application context as a source folder, and VOILA! I am pretty sure there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Spring supplies some tools that can help with such testing.  See [Spring TestContext Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#testcontext-framework).